# Centralized rsyslog : max size of message

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rsyslog

I configured a centralized syslog on Ubuntu 12.04.

I set the max message size on both servers

```
$MaxMessageSize 20k
```

I have 2 different comportment :

- client : message are logged completly
- server : message are truncated at 2k

I can find configuration of any other buffer size.

Is it a limitation of rsyslog or a configuration problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Fred

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution.

The parameter :

```
$MaxMessageSize 20k
```

must be set before network declaration (at the top of rsyslog.conf file) :

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 1514
```