# How to increase php syslog maximum limit of 2048

Tags: php, debugging, logging, syslog, rsyslog

Is there a simple way to log message greater than 2048 char using syslog? e.g raw response of a curl request.

```
// msg is a string > 2048 char. This truncates message to 2048 chars
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, msg);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2K limit might come from rsyslog, too (it's the default limit). You should be able to change it with something like:

```
$MaxMessageSize 10k
```

And put it somewhere at the beginning of the config:

[Centralized rsyslog : max size of message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619933/centralized-rsyslog-max-size-of-message)